# Add User to UserList for Google Ads Remarketing

Tags: node.js, google-ads-api

**Problem**: I can't figure out how, using the Node.js [google-ads-api](https://opteo.com/dev/google-ads-api/#features), to add a user to a Google Ads remarketing user list.

I can create the user list:

```js
async createUserList() {
    const mutation = await this.customer.userLists.create({
        name: '<USERLIST_NAME>',
        membership_life_span: 60,
        membership_status: enums.UserListMembershipStatus.OPEN,
        basic_user_list: {
            actions: [{
                remarketing_action: '<REMARKETING_ACTION_RESOURCE_NAME>',
            }]
        }
    })
    console.log(`created userlist ${mutation.results[0]}`)
    return mutation.results[0]
}
```

I'm still trying to read the [Google Ads Api documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/remarketing/overview) to see if I'm misunderstanding the intended workflow with remarketing, but I do expect adding users to a user list programmatically to be a supported functionality.

Answer (score 0):

For adding users to a Google Ads remarketing user list you should use [OfflineUserDataJobService](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v6/OfflineUserDataJobService).

Also, [here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/migration/user-data-service) some useful information if you are migrating from the AdWords API.

Comment: @Dymtro Los - do you have any idea whether google ads API (not Adwords API) support rest JSON for adding / removing the users to the userlist?